# Rails: violates foreign key constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reference, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have three models: `Book`, `genre`, `BookGenre`, and here are relationships:

```
class BookGenre < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :genre
end


class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_genres
  has_many :genres, through: :book_genres
end


class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_genres
  has_many :books, through: :book_genres
end
```

And then I use `seed` file to put data into these tables.

But when I want to do `rake db:seed` again, it showed this error

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "books" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_4a117802d7" on table "book_genres"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(10) is still referenced from table "book_genres".
```

In my **seed.rb**

```
Book.destroy_all
Genre.destroy_all
...create data
```

Comment: yeah! you have been a great help, thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add `dependent: :destroy` option to your `has_many` definitions.

[Check docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many)

Yet better option to respect data integrity is to set the `CASCADE DELETE` on the database level: say, you have `comments` table and `users` table. User has many comments You want to add a foreign_key to table `comments` and set deleting the comment whenever the user is destroyed you would go with the following (the `on_delete: :cascade` option will ensure it):

```
add_foreign_key(
  :comments,
  :users,
  column:
  :user_id,
  on_delete: :cascade
)
```

Comment: how do you set that at the database level?

Comment: @JonathanTuzman `add_foreign_key(
      :comments,
      :users,
      column: :user_id,
      on_delete: :cascade
    )`

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disable_referential_integrity do
    Book.destroy_all
    Genre.destroy_all
    # ...create data 
end
```