# Can't delete a record with Object.delete(params[:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My destroy action is throwing this error:

```
 Failure/Error: Deal.delete(params[:id])

 ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey:
   PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "deals" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_cc6e075aca" on table "origin_airports"
```

The action:

```
def destroy
  Deal.delete(params[:id])
  redirect_to deals_path
end
```

I've found answers about this (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826409/rails-violates-foreign-key-constraint)) and adjusted my `Deal` class thusly:

```
has_many :origin_airports, dependent: :destroy
has_many :origins, through: :origin_airports, source: :airport
```

But I still get the same error.

PS. The designated answer for the post referenced above says "Yet better option to respect data integrity is to set the CASCADE DELETE on the database level." I'd love to know how to do that.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You should retrieve the object and then call `destroy` on it instead of using the class method of `delete(id)`

So try this:

```
deal = Deal.find(params[:id])
deal.destroy
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `:dependent` option to:

`:destroy` when the object is destroyed, #destroy will be called on its associated objects.

`:delete` when the object is destroyed, all its associated objects will be deleted directly from the database without calling their #destroy method.

As per your settings, you have to do `deal.destroy` and not `deal.delete`.

You can also try (migration):

```
def change
  remove_foreign_key "model1", "model2"
  add_foreign_key "model1", "mnodel2", on_delete: :cascade
end
```

No data is lost since they are only indexes.